# drywall inspection

Tags: drywall, code-compliance

The city I am in requires me to get a drywall inspection for a new wall. Should I have the inspection done before I mud and tape? What are the issues that drywall inspectors are looking for?

Comment: Call your inspector's office and ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because local inspections are very location-specific

Comment: They check to see if fasteners and fastener spacing is appropriate, they check for fasteners that have punched through the paper, they check for appropriate fire-rated drywall (type-x) where required, they check for overlarge gaps that would compromise fire rating. My AHJ does it before mud & tape.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it  I would +1 your comment, if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They check to see if fasteners and fastener spacing is appropriate, they check for fasteners that have punched through the paper, they check for appropriate fire-rated drywall (type-x) where required, they check for overlarge gaps that would compromise fire rating. My AHJ does it before mud & tape.

Comment: Add in the use of greenboard or concrete board where appropriate in bathrooms and shower areas.  (although greenboard is entirely not needed if room is painted correctly but they don't do painting inspections)